# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.OpenApi'... while using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli

Tags: c#, reflection, dependencies, asp.net-core-2.0, assembly-loading

I'm getting the subject error message while using the sample MS PowerShell script from the article [Generating API clients using AutoRest](https://www.patriksvensson.se/2018/10/generating-api-clients-using-autorest) when the following command line

```
dotnet swagger "tofile" --output "../../res/swagger.json" "../Sample.Api/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/Sample.Api.dll" v1
```

is executed. Solution?

FYI: Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli entry source code is located here: [Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/src/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli/Program.cs](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli/Program.cs)

**UPDATE**

I should have posted the full text of runtime error message - here it is:

```
At C:\Tests\Swashbuckle\build.ps1:8 char:1
+ dotnet swagger "tofile" --output "../../res/swagger.json" "../Sample. ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:String) [], RemoteException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Unhandled Exception:

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.OpenApi, 
     Version=1.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3f5743946376f042'. 
     The system cannot find the file specified.
at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli.Program.<>c.<Main>b__0_3(IDictionary`2 namedArgs)
at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli.CommandRunner.Run(IEnumerable`1 args)
at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli.CommandRunner.Run(IEnumerable`1 args)
at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used the following to get rid of this issue.

Upgraded swagger to 5.0.0-rc3, my csproj looks like this

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.0.0-rc3" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Then I installed the swagger cli using following code as you must have installed

```
dotnet tool install -g swashbuckle.aspnetcore.cli --version 5.0.0-rc3
```

And finally running the command

```
swagger "tofile" --output "../../res/swagger.json" "../Sample.Api/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/Sample.Api.dll" v1
```

make sure you have swagger in your path after running the above command.

Answer (score 1):

The issue solved by referencing v.4.0.1 (or v.5.0.0-beta) of Swashbuckle.AspNetCore and Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations packages and of Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli tool:

```
...
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
   <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="4.0.1" />
   <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations" Version="4.0.1" />
</ItemGroup>

 <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli" Version="4.0.1" />
 </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Which version of .Net core are you using? Does it work with .Net core 3.1?